# Tikz: Filling up plane defined by equation with a particular colour

Tags: tikz-pgf, asymptote, tikz-3dplot

I'm trying to draw planes using their equations using \addplot3. Problems start to occur when I want to fill the planes with colour. I want to fill them with colour, just as I would be able to do had I defined my plane by a set of coordinates. Here is my code:

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2.5]
\begin{axis}[
title={Intersecting planes}, 
xlabel=$x$, ylabel=$y$, zlabel = $z$,zlabel style={rotate=-90},
small,
]


\addplot3[
fill=blue,
domain=-5:5,
domain y=-5:5,
] {x + 2*y -1};

\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Caption}
\label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure}
```

The output is then

How do I edit the code to make the plane a solid blue?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried increasing the sample count of the plot operation  (passing e.g. `samples=100` as an additional option)?

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass[border=1 cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
xlabel=$x$, ylabel=$y$, zlabel = $z$,
]
\addplot3[
surf, shader=flat,
blue,
domain=-5:5,
domain y=-5:5,
samples=2,
] {x + 2*y -1};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Blue surface plot]

-or with `fill` and another `draw` color:

```
\documentclass[border=1 cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
xlabel=$x$, ylabel=$y$, zlabel = $z$,
]
\addplot3[
surf, shader=flat,
fill=blue, draw=orange,
domain=-5:5,
domain y=-5:5,
samples =10,
] {x + 2*y -1};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Blue surface with orange grid]

Answer (score 0):

`fill=blue` is just not the right key for this. Please notice that unless you use keys like `axis equal` different axes will undergo different scalings. Note also that for intersecting planes you may want to transition to `patch plots`. This is just to show that you get a blue plane when dialing the right keys. (The fact that it is blue is an accident because the color map happens to give it here, but of course it is possible to install any color one wants.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2.5]
\begin{axis}[
title={Intersecting planes}, 
xlabel=$x$, ylabel=$y$, zlabel = $z$,zlabel style={rotate=-90},
small,
]


\addplot3[surf,point meta=0,shader=interp,
domain=-5:5,
domain y=-5:5,
] {x + 2*y -1};

\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Caption}
\label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is an Asymptote way. Run on http://asymptote.ualberta.ca/
PS: I am not so comfortable when controlling light in Asymptote.

[image]

```
// the plane z = x + 2 y - 1 
unitsize(1cm,1cm,3mm);
import graph3;
currentprojection=orthographic(2,1,2,zoom=.9,center=true);
currentlight=light(5,5,16);
pair A=(-5,-5), B=(5,5);
real f(pair M){return M.x+2*M.y-1;}
surface s=surface(f,A,B);
pen p=blue+opacity(.5);
draw(s,p);

xaxis3("$x$",Bounds,purple,InTicks);
yaxis3("$y$",Bounds,purple,InTicks);
zaxis3("$z$",Bounds,purple,InTicks);

dot("$O$",align=N,O,red);
```